# ASP.NET user registration data

Tags: asp.net

I have created an ASP.NET MVC 5 application, which uses MongoDB as a database. The application allows users to register and log in as standard. I want to know how I can reset this, i.e. remove all user names. Which directory is all this registration data stored? Am I right in thinking that the user registration / authentication system has nothing to do with the MongoDB database? Thanks :)

Comment: How did you create the action?  From the MVC template in VS?

Comment: AFAIK the default db provider for membership is a SQL database.  Im sure this is automatically created using EF/Code first implementation, this used to be a aspnet_reg{something} command.

Comment: And yes, the MongoDB database shouldn't be used for users (by default).  I dont know whether you could write a provider for this, I guess you could.